# drag and drop in flash cc 2015 with createjs

Tags: flash, drag-and-drop, createjs

can anyone know how to do simple drag and drop in flash canvas with createjs ?

```
this.circle.addEventListener("pressmove", fl_MouseClickHandler_2.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2()
{
    // Start your custom code
    // This example code displays the words "Mouse clicked" in the Output panel.
    evt.target.x = evt.stageX;
    evt.target.y = evt.stageY;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Your example is missing an event parameter in your method. It should work otherwise.

Comment: yes that's it thank you